# Is there a way to use eval() and a dictionary if input could be None?

Tags: python, eval, nonetype

I have some code with a lot of stacked `if` statements that I'm trying to make more pythonic. One of the segments of code boils down to three separate "values".

```
0.9 if 10<x>=20
0.75 if x>20
1 if x<10 or x is None
```

I tried sticking this in a dictionary to run through a function I made for a less complex (integers only) dictionary but am not sure how to handle `None` inputs.

```
def wallrat(val, table):
    try:
        # Create true/false list based on input value
        chks = [eval(v.replace('x',str(val))) for v in table.values()]
        # Find which value is true and verify that there's only one true value
        if True in chks and chks.count(True) == 1:
            # find the key that's true
            v = chks.index(True)
            table_list = list(table)
            # Loop through keys and values in dictionary
            return table_list[v]

age_dict = {0.9: '10< x >=20', 0.75: 'x > 20', 1:'x<10 or x is None'}
```

The above code obviously errors since if `x == None`, it can't do the other evaluations of `10< None >=20`. I'm not sure how to pythonically handle this situation. Is it even possible to have a dictionary that tests both `None` and ints/floats? Or am I stuck having to use only `x < 10` and use a separate segment of code to output the value of 1 if the input is `None`?

EDIT: I don't want to delete the question, but ended up just utilizing an If ... is not 'None' and an else statement to capture the 'None' = 1 assignment.

Comments and answers may provide helpful reconsideration to others utilizing eval(). In my specific use-case, there is no way for the input to contain malicious strings due to what the input data is (GIS feature class tables with integer fields or a coded int variable based on input date fields). Regardless though, I wasn't aware of the concerns about using eval() and the comments provide good information IMO.

Comment: Not clear why the logic is handled in this way, but the None case can be handled in the same way: `{0.9:'10<x>=20 if x is not None else False', 0.75:'x>20  if x is not None else False', 1:'x is None or x<10'}`

Comment: I'd suggest that using `eval` in this way is *less* pythonic than just using explicit if/else tests.

Comment: You seem to be using `eval` to avoid a function call, but `eval` *is* a function call, with the additional overhead of having to parse the expression stored in your `dict`.

Comment: @match , while this specific dictionary is only 3 values, I use the same function for a few different dicts in the code so figured I could re-purpose it for this one as well. It reduced 70ish lines of code down to just 10 or so. Unless you mean specifically just the None segment and...yeah, it may best be just handled by doing a "if not none, do function, if null, assign 1."

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list of lambdas that contain the logic you need instead of `eval` as it is a potential security risk and almost always not needed.

```
checks = [lambda x: .75 if x > 20 else ..., lambda x: 1 if x is None or x < 10 else ...]
```

Comment: Why is eval a security risk?

Comment: @JackOfTales You are asking a possibly untrusted user for arbitrary code that you will execute on their behalf.

Comment: The code is running on an CSV input that is output by a system that uses Domains for specific explicit fields (for example, it can only take YES instead of yes, Yes, yEs so there's no reason to code for .lower on that field's input). The variables feeding into the eval come from a table field of floats and nulls and aren't capable of being strings. That said, if there's a way to look at 3+ fields of int/float inputs, compare them against different numeric comparisons, and assign a single value without using 100+ lines of code...I'd be happy to know!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this if/else test in a single line, then using the python ternary syntax is probably the most readable option, and much safer & faster than `eval` with a dictionary of tests:

```
1 if x is None or x < 10 else 0.9 if 10 <= x <= 20 else 0.75
```